# How to structure the data for a 2 person muliplayer game using Firestore and Swift?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

First of all I'm really new to Firestore and its functionalities, so I apologize if some of this might feel obvious to others. These things are just not registering in my mind yet.

I'm trying to create a 2 person multiplayer game using the language Swift and Firestore as the backend. However I'm not to sure how to create this functionality of only allowing two players inside a single game at a given time. How would I go about restricting each game to only allowing two players inside one game? Would this be something I need to set up within the security and rules portion of Firestore? Or would I need to create this functionality within how I model my data?

My current setup for how I'm modeling the data includes creating a collection of "Games" where each "Game" has two documents for "player1" and "player2". Then, within each one of those players/documents I store the values of each players functionalities. But with this approach, I still haven't solved the issue of only allowing two players within a single "Game"/collection. How do I prevent a third player from entering the game? or how would I handle the situation when more than one person enters a game at the same time?

Thank you for any advice possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cloud Functions to assign players to a game, manage when a game is full and then start it.  Take a look at this article on Medium, [Building a multi-player board game with Firebase Firestore & Functions](https://medium.com/@feloy/building-a-multi-player-board-game-with-firebase-firestore-functions-part-1-17527c5716c5)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. These cloud functions and triggers have solved all my problems, and this article gave me a much more logical approach for structuring my data in Firestore.

Comment: You're most welcome. You stated in your question that you're new to this and reached out for help, yet people have down voted your question. I really don't understand why. This is supposed to be a community for developers to help each other

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I ended up creating in Swift using Firestore to create the 2 person multiplayer game.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class WaitForOpponentViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var battleRoomDocumentReference : DocumentReference!
    var battleRoomListenerRegistration : ListenerRegistration!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

         activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
         activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        Firestore.firestore().collection(BATTLEROOMS_Collection)
            .whereField(BATTLEROOMFULL_FIELD, isEqualTo: false)
            .whereField(NUMOFPLAYERS_FIELD, isLessThan: 2)
            .limit(to: 1)
            .getDocuments { (snapShot, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("There was a error while fetching the documents: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                guard let snap = snapShot else {return}
                if(snap.documents.count > 0)
                {
                    //Update the current battle room
                    for document in snap.documents
                    {
                        Firestore.firestore().collection(BATTLEROOMS_Collection)
                            .document(document.documentID)
                            .setData(
                                [
                                    BATTLEROOMFULL_FIELD : true,
                                    NUMOFPLAYERS_FIELD : 2, //Note: Player1Id is not changed because there is already a player1Id when this document is updated
                                    PLAYER2ID_FIELD : Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "AnonymousNum2"
                                ], options: SetOptions.merge(), completion: { (error) in

                                    if let error = error
                                    {
                                        print("There was an error while adding the second player to the battle room document : \(error)")
                                    }

                                    self.addBattleRoomListener(battleRoomDocumentId: document.documentID)
                          })
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      //Create a new battle room
                      self.battleRoomDocumentReference =  Firestore.firestore().collection(BATTLEROOMS_Collection)
                           .addDocument(data:
                            [
                                BATTLEROOMFULL_FIELD: false,
                                NUMOFPLAYERS_FIELD : 1,
                                PLAYER1ID_FIELD : Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "AnonymousNum1",
                                PLAYER2ID_FIELD : ""
                            ], completion: { (error) in

                                if let error = error
                                {
                                    print("Error while adding a new battle room/player 1 to the battle room document : \(error)")
                                }
                    })
                    self.addBattleRoomListener(battleRoomDocumentId: self.battleRoomDocumentReference.documentID)
                }
            }
        }
     }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        //Remove Battle Room Listener
        battleRoomListenerRegistration.remove()

        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    func addBattleRoomListener(battleRoomDocumentId : String)
    {
        battleRoomListenerRegistration = Firestore.firestore().collection(BATTLEROOMS_Collection)
            .document(battleRoomDocumentId)
            .addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in

                guard let snapshot = documentSnapshot else { return }
                guard let documentData = snapshot.data() else { return }
                let battleRoomFullData = documentData[BATTLEROOMFULL_FIELD] as? Bool ?? false
                let numOfPlayerData = documentData[NUMOFPLAYERS_FIELD] as? Int ?? 0

                if(battleRoomFullData == true && numOfPlayerData == 2)
                {
                    print("Two Players in the Game, HURRAY. Segue to GAME VIEW CONTROLLER")
                }
                else
                {
                    return
                }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancelBattle(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //NOTE: Canceling is only allowed for the first user thats creates the Battle Room, once the Second Person enters the Battle Room the system will automatically segue to the Game View Controller sending both players into the game VC

        Firestore.firestore().collection(BATTLEROOMS_Collection)
            .document(battleRoomDocumentReference.documentID)
            .delete { (error) in
                if let error = error
                {
                    print("There was an error while trying to delete a document: \(error)")
                }
        }

        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```